# React Redux element not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a Table component, which renders rows for items list:

```
return <Row style={styles.row} key={idx} item={item} onSelect={this.props.onRowSelect}>
    {columns.map((col, idx) => {
        return <Column style={col.style} key={`${item._id}_${col.key}`}
                       width={col.width || this._defaultCellWidth} type={col.type}>
            {_.get(item, col.key)}
        </Column>
    })}
    </Row>
```

each item has `selected:bool` value, which is binded to a checkbox on each row.

Also, I have a HeaderRow, which has checkbox for select all.
By checking the checkbox I dispatch an event to update the selected field.
The state itself is updated, but there is no rerender.
My action is:

```
if(action.id) 
{
    let index = state.items.findIndex(item => item._id == action.id);
    state.items[index].selected = action.selected;
}
else
{
    state.items.map(e=>e.selected = action.selected);
}

return 
{
    ...state,
    items: state.items
}
```

EDIT: 
Is that good solution:

```
if(action.id) {
            let index = state.items.findIndex(item => item._id == action.id);
            state.items[index].selected = action.selected;
            return {
                ...state
            }

        }else{
            return {
                ...state,
                items: state.items.map((item, index) => {
                    return Object.assign({}, item, {
                        selected: action.selected
                    })
                })
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that [all data in the Redux store must be considered immutable](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html#immutable-data-management) (["[a reducer] must never mutate its arguments"](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#handling-actions)).

You're mutating the items within `state.items`, and since `items` remains the same object, Redux considers it unchanged, so the view is not updated.

Comment: So how can I set only one item in the array and tell react it's updated?

Answer (score 0):

Just a common error that often happens. Take a look at [this article](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html), as it explains how you can safely update each kind of level.

In your case it should something like this:

```
return 
{
    // Copy the current state
    ...state,
    // Replace the items array with a new version,
    // by creating a new array through the map() call.
    items: state.items.map((item, index) => {
        // This isn't the item in the array we are looking
        // for. So simply return it as is.
        if(index != action.id) {
            return item;
        }

        // This is the item to be changed. So copy it and
        // overwrite the selected property.
        return {
            ...item,
            selected: action.selected
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, because now all the Rows are rendering (I pring that in the row render function). So I guess now it thinks all the items had changed.

Comment: Then you have to further break down your containers and components. Maybe you should take a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYzlpRvWZ6c) or [this component](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/).